# UITableView at iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I encountered a problem at swift 4.0 . I've added AppleMap inside of TableView, when i touch to map, it needs to add pin that location. But when touchesBegan started, it wont add pin at map.

```
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? HimBasvuruCell
    for touch in touches {
        let touchPoint = touch.location(in: cell?.mapView)
        let location =  cell?.mapView.convert(touchPoint, toCoordinateFrom: cell?.mapView)
        print ("\(location!.latitude), \(location?.longitude)")
        addAnnotation(location: location!)
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this -> `let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! HimBasvuruCell' or may be `if let`.

Comment: You should take a look at [delaysContentTouches](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619398-delayscontenttouches)

Comment: Does your mapView have `User Interaction Enabled`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have build a project and test it works fine, drag a table view into ViewController and add a mapView on cells . Fist in your cell class should be like:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    // define a function if you need to use map info in ViewController
     var mapAction: (() -> ())?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        mapView.delegate = self

       mapAction()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool ) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(handleTap))
        gestureRecognizer.delegate = self
        mapView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)

    }

  @objc  func handleTap(gestureReconizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        let location = gestureReconizer.location(in: mapView)
        let coordinate = mapView.convert(location,toCoordinateFrom: mapView)

        // Add annotation:
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = coordinate
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }


}
```

then your tableView should confirm its delegates in your ViewController class

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self 
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
         cell.mapAction = { [unowned self] in

          print("\(cell.mapView.annotations[indexpath.row])")
         }
        return cell
    }


}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

touchesBegan will not get called as you are using table view

Comment: So, how can i solve this? Is there any solution for clicking map inside of tableview?

Comment: Use Tap gesture